# How to split string field value by two delimiters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, split

I have the client table with string value field called `Address` separated by commas and spaces. I want a query to split the address by the space and the comma into separate columns. I could split the string by one delimiter but unfortunately couldn't find a way to split by two.

Please help.

Here is the existing table and the resulting table that should be generated:

[image: Here is the existing table and the resulting table that should be generated]

Comment: Don't attempt to do this in SQL Server.  Instead, handle this outside of your database.

Comment: Hi, you mean handle this inside my source code right (I am using .net application)?

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with the "Don't attempt to do this in SQL Server. Instead, handle this outside of your database" comment. However, we can use the following code to overcome thisissue.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #YourAdressTable
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempAdressTable
GO
CREATE table #YourAdressTable
    ([id] int, name varchar(100), [ColumnName] varchar(100))

CREATE table #TempAdressTable
    ([id] int, name varchar(100), splitted_adress varchar(100),[ColumnName] varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #YourAdressTable VALUES (1,'Sam','10 HillRoad Mexico')
INSERT INTO #YourAdressTable VALUES (2,'John','No.32,HelenaLane,Bothel')
INSERT INTO #YourAdressTable VALUES (3,'Smith','23/C/2 HillStreet,BomBay,NewColumn_Bombay')

INSERT INTO #TempAdressTable
SELECT id,name,value ,CONCAT('Adress',ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY name 
   ) ) as ColumnName 
FROM #YourAdressTable
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(ColumnName,',',' '),' ')


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select   @cols=STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) 
                    from #TempAdressTable
                    group by ColumnName
             
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT id,name,' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select id,name,splitted_adress, ColumnName
                from #TempAdressTable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(splitted_adress)
                for ColumnName in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p  order by id'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

[image]