# SQL query that will return results separated by commas

Tags: sql, sql-server

I has two tables on MS SQL Server. First with the cities, second with student names and city ID from first table, where this student lives.

I need a sql query that will return results like this:

```
Stella Paris

Bob Moscow,New York

Mary Paris,New York
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: use [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and then [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Best option is to fix your design.

Comment: You can check this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69400803/how-to-split-string-field-value-by-two-delimiters-in-sql-server/69404365#69404365

Comment: What is the best way to redesign the database? Use a dedicated columns for each cities id's?

Comment: To record N-N dependencies you have to create relation table, `students_cities`, containig ID-s from both tables (so called foreign keys).

Comment: This really is a bad design antipattern, the data should be properly *normalised*, never store multiple values in a single column.

Comment: Thnaks to all. I will redesign the database!

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CITIES(ID,CITY_NAME)AS
(
    SELECT 1,'MOSCOW' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'PARIS' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'NEW YORK'
 ),
 STUDENTS(ID,STUDENT_NAME,LIVE_IN) AS
 (
   SELECT 1,'STELLA','2' UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,'BOB','1,3' UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,'MARY','2,3'
 )
 SELECT X.ID,X.STUDENT_NAME,STRING_AGG(X.CITY_NAME,',')CITY_NAME FROM
  ( 
     SELECT S.ID,S.STUDENT_NAME,VALUE AS CITY_ID,C.CITY_NAME
     FROM STUDENTS AS S
     CROSS APPLY string_split(S.LIVE_IN,',')
     JOIN CITIES AS C ON VALUE=C.ID
  )X
 GROUP BY X.ID,X.STUDENT_NAME;
```

For SQL Server 2017 and later, as pointed by @Squirrel, you can use STRING_SPLIT and STRING_AGG

Comment: I has a SQL Server 2019

Comment: Perfect.Then this query should work for you

Answer (score -1):

Steps you can use:-

1. Use two different queries
2. first returning students records
3. then loop through to get cities records
4. update the array data as required

A better suggestion would be redesign database so as to be used table JOIN